# errors in GWT program

Tags: gwt, rpc

I am developing a simple app (using GWT RPC & Hibernate) to insert data into database & retrieve. It was working fine with adding user method.

Now I write a method to retrieve data from database & display. It is raising source path errors when module is loaded into browser.

The structure of project in eclipse is:

```
-src
-user.hbm.xml
-hibernate.cfg.xml
   ->rpctest
     ->Rpctest.gwt.xml  
   ->rpctest.hibDomain
     ->User.java
   ->rpctest.client
     ->Rpctest.java
     ->service interfaces
   ->rpctest.server
     ->service implementation
     ->HibernateUtil.java
```

Here is stack trace:

```
    [DEBUG] [rpctest] - Validating newly compiled units
[TRACE] [rpctest] - Finding entry point classes
    [ERROR] [rpctest] - Unable to find type 'rpctest.client.Rpctest'
        [ERROR] [rpctest] - Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
        [ERROR] [rpctest] - Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[ERROR] [rpctest] - Failed to load module 'rpctest' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)' at 127.0.0.1:49465
```

**Rpctest.gwt.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='rpctest'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='rpctest.client.Rpctest'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='rpctest.client.Rpctest'/>
  <source path='server'/>
  <source path='hibDomain.User'/>


 </module>
```

Comment: could you paste the User class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class User in the hibDomain package is not included in your gwt source path

You can configure the classes that the gwt compiler should translate to javascript by adding them in your gwt xml file. Take a look at the docs: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml

Comment: I added the 'User' class to GWT project in 'Rpctest.gwt.xml' like, <source path="rpctest.hibDomain.User" /> , where 'rpctest' is package under src & hibDomain is folder containing the User class file. But same error is raising.

Comment: the source path is relative to your gwt xml file

Comment: I made it like 'hibDomain.User' now. As both 'hibDomain' folder containing 'User.java' & 'rpctest' folder containing 'gwt.xml' are in 'src' folder. But same errors :(

Comment: though this problem is still to be solved but as I knew the reason of the error i.e. source path parameters through your answer. I better close this thread as I open a new one. Thank you Daniel for the help.